Interpolate among Groups in pandas DataFrame
I'm looking for the most efficient way to interpolate across Groups in pandas DataFrame for a big data volume. For example I have some groups that have all the values, and some that have none. In the example below data is groupby('Group'), Groups A and D have all the values at all Time, and Groups B,C and E have none.
How to find the most efficient way to interpolate Group E based on Group D specifically, giving the logic that Group D is the nearest and thus to be used for interpolation.
I am new to python.
  Group  Time  Value
    A    1     10
    A    2     15
    A    3     30
    A    4     50
    B    1     NaN
    B    2     NaN
    B    3     NaN
    B    4     NaN
    C    1     NaN
    C    2     NaN
    C    3     NaN
    C    4     NaN
    D    1     5
    D    2     10
    D    3     15
    D    4     20
    E    1     NaN
    E    2     NaN
    E    3     NaN
    E    4     NaN

The expected output is something like the below
  Group  Time  Value
    A    1     10
    A    2     15
    A    3     30
    A    4     50
    B    1     10
    B    2     15
    B    3     30
    B    4     50
    C    1     5
    C    2     10
    C    3     15
    C    4     20
    D    1     5
    D    2     10
    D    3     15
    D    4     20
    E    1     5
    E    2     10
    E    3     15
    E    4     20


What about a df.groupby('Time').ffill()?

Regarding "most efficient way", don't worry about that yet. Figure out a way to do it, then worry about whether it's efficient enough. You might want to read Which is faster? by Eric Lippert and What makes a "good" performance question on SO?

What do you mean by "nearest"? I mean, are groups considered "near" based on their names (A, B, etc) or based on their position (1, 2, etc)? The situation I have in mind is groups that go like L (data), M (no data), N (no data), Z (data).

Do any groups have only some values?

I think I found a solution, but it's pretty convoluted so I want to work out most of the kinks before I post it.

You could try this :
#Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Group': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E'],
    'Time': [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4,],
    'Value': [10, 15, 30, 50, '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 5, 10, 15, 20, '', '', '', '']
})


df['Value'] = df['Value'].replace('', np.nan)

#Arrange the DataFrame as required

df['Group'] = pd.Categorical(df['Group'], categories=['A','B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])

#Decide Interpolation Method
interpolation_type = 'linear'
df_new = df.groupby('Time')['Value'].apply(lambda x: x.interpolate(method=interpolation_type))

#Rearrange new dataframe in original order
df_new = df_new.swaplevel(0,1).sort_index()

df['Value'] = df_new.values
df

Output
Group   Time    Value
0   A   1   10.000000
1   A   2   15.000000
2   A   3   30.000000
3   A   4   50.000000
4   B   1   8.333333
5   B   2   13.333333
6   B   3   25.000000
7   B   4   40.000000
8   C   1   6.666667
9   C   2   11.666667
10  C   3   20.000000
11  C   4   30.000000
12  D   1   5.000000
13  D   2   10.000000
14  D   3   15.000000
15  D   4   20.000000
16  E   1   5.000000
17  E   2   10.000000
18  E   3   15.000000
19  E   4   20.000000


Assuming you want to fill based on the nearest group and that groups are unique (i.e. there won't be another stretch of A after the first one).
You could convert the groups to ordered numbers with factorize, then split the DataFrame in two parts (complete/missing values) to perform a merge_asof on the group number by Time:
tmp = (df.assign(g=pd.factorize(df['Group'], sort=False)[0])
         .sort_values(by='g', kind='stable')
      )

m = tmp['Value'].isna()

missing = pd.merge_asof(
    tmp.loc[m, ['g', 'Time']].reset_index(),
    tmp.loc[~m, ['g', 'Time', 'Value']],
    on='g', by='Time',
    allow_exact_matches=False,
    direction='nearest'
).set_index('index')['Value']

df.loc[missing.index, 'Value'] = missing

Output:
   Group  Time  Value
0      A     1   10.0
1      A     2   15.0
2      A     3   30.0
3      A     4   50.0
4      B     1   10.0
5      B     2   15.0
6      B     3   30.0
7      B     4   50.0
8      C     1    5.0
9      C     2   10.0
10     C     3   15.0
11     C     4   20.0
12     D     1    5.0
13     D     2   10.0
14     D     3   15.0
15     D     4   20.0
16     E     1    5.0
17     E     2   10.0
18     E     3   15.0
19     E     4   20.0

Intermediates:
   Group  Time  Value  g  closest_g  filled_Value
0      A     1   10.0  0        NaN           NaN
1      A     2   15.0  0        NaN           NaN
2      A     3   30.0  0        NaN           NaN
3      A     4   50.0  0        NaN           NaN
4      B     1    NaN  1        0.0          10.0
5      B     2    NaN  1        0.0          15.0
6      B     3    NaN  1        0.0          30.0
7      B     4    NaN  1        0.0          50.0
8      C     1    NaN  2        3.0           5.0
9      C     2    NaN  2        3.0          10.0
10     C     3    NaN  2        3.0          15.0
11     C     4    NaN  2        3.0          20.0
12     D     1    5.0  3        NaN           NaN
13     D     2   10.0  3        NaN           NaN
14     D     3   15.0  3        NaN           NaN
15     D     4   20.0  3        NaN           NaN
16     E     1    NaN  4        3.0           5.0
17     E     2    NaN  4        3.0          10.0
18     E     3    NaN  4        3.0          15.0
19     E     4    NaN  4        3.0          20.0

NB. In case of a tie between two groups (C is equidistant to A and E in the example below), the previous one will be used. If you rather want to use the next one you should add - to factorize (df.assign(g=-pd.factorize(df['Group'], sort=False)[0])).
Example:
   Group  Time  Value  g  closest_g  filled_Value
0      A     1   10.0  0        NaN           NaN
1      A     2   15.0  0        NaN           NaN
2      A     3   30.0  0        NaN           NaN
3      A     4   50.0  0        NaN           NaN
4      B     1    NaN -1        0.0          10.0
5      B     2    NaN -1        0.0          15.0
6      B     3    NaN -1        0.0          30.0
7      B     4    NaN -1        0.0          50.0
8      C     1    NaN -2       -4.0           5.0
9      C     2    NaN -2       -4.0          10.0
10     C     3    NaN -2       -4.0          15.0
11     C     4    NaN -2       -4.0          20.0
12     D     1    NaN -3       -4.0           5.0
13     D     2    NaN -3       -4.0          10.0
14     D     3    NaN -3       -4.0          15.0
15     D     4    NaN -3       -4.0          20.0
16     E     1    5.0 -4        NaN           NaN
17     E     2   10.0 -4        NaN           NaN
18     E     3   15.0 -4        NaN           NaN
19     E     4   20.0 -4        NaN           NaN

